# custom headers are not being merged with axios instance headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have created below base instance with default configs,

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { CUSTOMER_SERVICE_URL } = require('config');

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: CUSTOMER_SERVICE_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Client-Id': 'fadfs',
    'X-Api-Key': 'asdfasrwrwerw',
  },
});

module.exports = instance;
```

Now, I need to attach some headers with variable values,

```
const res = await instance.get(`/zones/${zone_id}/slots`, {
    headers: {
      'X-User-Id': user_id,
      'X-Api-Hash': createApiHash({
        userId: user_id,
        apiKey: CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CREDS.CUSTOMER_API_KEY,
        clientId: CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CREDS.CUSTOMER_CLIENT_ID,
        apiSecret: CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CREDS.CUSTOMER_API_SECRET,
      }),
    },
  });
  if (!res.data.status) {
    throw new BadRequestError(res.data.message);
  }
```

But, In the request to the service when I log headers It doesn't list `X-User-Id` and `X-Api-Hash`.

```
{
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'x-client-id': 'sasdfsdvmgr',
  'x-api-key': 'werwerwer',
  'user-agent': 'axios/0.21.1',
  'content-length': '232',
  host: 'localhost:3001',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake this is the signature for `instance.put`

```
axios#put(url[, data[, config]])
```

So,

```
const res = await instance.put('/admin/bookings', {
    item_id,
    order_id,
    reasons_ids,
    other_reason,
    service_request_id,
    status: REQUEST_CANCELLED,
  }, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'X-User-Id': user_id,
      'X-Api-Hash': createApiHash({
        userId: user_id,
        apiKey: CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CREDS.CUSTOMER_API_KEY,
        clientId: CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CREDS.CUSTOMER_CLIENT_ID,
        apiSecret: CUSTOMER_SERVICE_CREDS.CUSTOMER_API_SECRET,
      }),
    },
  });
  if (!res.data.status) {
    throw new BadRequestError(res.data.message);
  }
```